# Show any any set of any $5$ vectors in $\mathbb {GF(3)}^3$ contains three vectors such that those $3$ vectors are linearly dependant.

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

> Show any any set of any $5$ vectors in $\mathbb {GF(3)}^3$ contains three vectors such that those $3$ vectors are linearly dependant.

I don't really know how to start, I have found an expample over $\mathbb R^3 $ that violates the above so $GF(3)$ is definitely relevant. Any hints?

Comment: @DilipSarwate There are $26=3^3-1$ non zero vectors in $\mathbb F_3^3$.. unless youre talking about vectors which dont have a $0$ at all.. Like $(0,1,0)$. This vector should be counted

Answer (score 2):

In effect, you are asking about points in the projective plane over $\Bbb F_3$.
In this context, this states that there are no five points with no three
of them collinear. Such sets are known as [arcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(projective_geometry)). Over $\Bbb F_q$ with $q$
odd it is well-known that an arc has at most $q+1$ points.

In our example, we can choose homogeneous coordinates such that four
of the points are $[1,0,0]$, $[0,1,0]$, $[0,0,1]$ and $[1,1,1]$. The six lines
joining these in pairs are $X=0$, $X=Y$ and those obtained from these by
permuting coordinates. These six lines cover the whole projective plane
so there can't be a fifth point.

Comment: Very nice! But I'm trying to teach my peers, is there any linear algebraic argument?